# Optimizing INNER JOINS SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW  
    customers.id,
    customers.customer_name  
FROM customers  
    INNER JOIN rentals ON customers.id = rentals.id_customer  
    INNER JOIN rentals_billing ON rentals.id = rentals_billing.id_rental  
    INNER JOIN vehicles ON vehicles.id = rentals.id_vehicle  
WHERE  
    (rentals_billing.customer_id_facsimile IS NULL AND rentals_billing.rental_payable = 1) 
    OR (
       (rentals_billing.missing_rent_id_doc IS NULL OR missing_rent_id_doc <= 0) 
        AND missing_rent_fee > 0
     ) 
    AND customers.delete_date IS NULL
    AND rentals.delete_date IS NULL
    AND vehicles.delete_date IS NULL
    AND (rentals.mode = 'MODEA' OR rentals.mode = 'MODEB' OR rentals.mode = 'MODEC')
```

Running on a MySQL server 5.6.13 (on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1) the virtual server is setup with 4Gb of RAM and a 2.1GHz processor (I think single core).

At the present time:

- table `customers` has around 3k records,
- table `rentals` has around 150k records,
- table `rentals_billing` has around 150k records,
- table `vehicles` has around 8k records

The query frequently goes in timeout (tooks more than 10-20 seconds).

I tried indexing some of the tables and keys involved in the query but without much luck.
There's a way to *optimize* such query ?

Best regards,
Mike

Comment: When you post a query optimization request, please include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table referenced by the query, or even better include a working dbfiddle. Use text, not screenshot images. That way people can answer more accurately, because they know your columns, data types, what indexes you have tried, etc. and they can test answers without having to type everything in by hand. Help us to help you!

Comment: Yikes, MySQL 5.6 is basically the same engine as from 2006. You're missing window functions, ctes, lateral joins, and a lot more... it doesn't really qualify as a modern database.

Comment: Also, that first `OR` is almost certainly wrong (you probably want another set of parentheses to group with the expression above it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `AND` has precedence over `OR`, so you have

```
WHERE
  (customer_id_facsimile IS NULL AND rentals_billing.rental_payable = 1)
OR 
  (
    (missing_rent_id_doc IS NULL OR missing_rent_id_doc <= 0) AND missing_rent_fee > 0)
    AND customers.delete_date IS NULL
    AND ...
  )
```

While this *may* be what you want, I guess you'll rather want

```
WHERE
(
  (customer_id_facsimile IS NULL AND rentals_billing.rental_payable = 1)
 OR 
  ((missing_rent_id_doc IS NULL OR missing_rent_id_doc <= 0) AND missing_rent_fee > 0)
)
AND customers.delete_date IS NULL
AND ...
```

Then `DISTINCTROW` (or more commonly just `DISTINCT`) is very often a sign for a poorly written query where someone joins several tables, produces loads of duplicate rows and then must get rid of the duplicates they created themselves. Such unnecessary big intermediate results can slow down a query a lot. And this is what you are doing here.

You want to select from customers, but only those that match certain criteria. So why the joins? Select `FROM customers` and filter in `WHERE`.

```
SELECT *
FROM customers c
WHERE c.delete_date IS NULL
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM rentals r
  JOIN rentals_billing rb on rb.id_rental = r.id
  JOIN vehicles v on v.id = r.id_vehicle AND v.delete_date IS NULL
  WHERE r.id_customer = c.id
  AND r.delete_date IS NULL
  AND r.mode IN ('MODEA', 'MODEB', 'MODEC')
  AND 
  (
    (???.customer_id_facsimile IS NULL AND rb.rental_payable = 1)
   or 
    ((rb.missing_rent_id_doc IS NULL OR rb.missing_rent_id_doc <= 0) AND ???.missing_rent_fee > 0)
  )
);
```

I've put `???` where I don't know which table the column belongs to.

To speed up the lookup you should have this index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON rentals (id_customer, mode, delete_date, id_vehicle);
```

Or, if most rentals are deleted:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON rentals (id_customer, delete_date, mode, id_vehicle);
```

Well, important is that id_customer comes first, because this is the column for which the lookup shall be made. These indexes are called covering indexes, because they contain all the columns you are using in the query. The first three are for the quick lookup, the id_vehicle then is for the join to vehicles, because you want to ensure that the rental is on a non-deleted vehicle. The rental ID that you need for the join to rentals_billing is silently included in the indexes in MySQL. In other DBMS you would have to explicitely add it.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply I'm going to apply all of your suggestions .. to may partial justification I'm not the original author of such query and I'm not a big expert in SQL, but I'm willing to learn ! :-)

Comment: I did it.. before indexing 65 seconds after indexing 2.9 seconds... thank you!

Comment: index creation can 'alter' the natual order of a table? I mean.. after creating such index I noticed that one query of the same database does not retrieve  records with the same order anymore ... btw the query was not using an "ORDER BY" clause so its order was not reilabile... but it's just to understand...

Comment: Well, without an `ORDER BY` clause a query result order is completely arbitrary. And yes, depending on how the DBMS accesses the data, the data will come in one order or another. If there is no index and the DBMS reads the table sequentially, the data will probably come in the order the data happens to be on disk. if it uses some parallel access it will probably come in another order and if it uses an index in will come yet in another order. But it shouldn't matter, for if you want a particular order, you'll use `ORDER BY`, and otherwise you don't care.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the indexes I would add to optimize the query you show:

```
ALTER TABLE rentals
  ADD INDEX (id_customer, id_vehicle, delete_date, mode);

ALTER TABLE rentals_billing
  ADD INDEX (id_rental, customer_id_facsimile, rental_payable,
    missing_rent_id_doc, missing_rent_fee);
```

I think the query must do a table-scan on `customers` regardless, and it will access `vehicles` by primary key.

I assume `id` is defined as a primary key in each table.

Here's the EXPLAIN I get when I test the query using MySQL 8.1.0:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: customers
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using temporary
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: rentals
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,id_customer
          key: id_customer
      key_len: 4
          ref: test.customers.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index; Distinct
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: rentals_billing
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: id_rental
          key: id_rental
      key_len: 4
          ref: test.rentals.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Distinct
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: vehicles
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: test.rentals.id_vehicle
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Distinct
```